Writing paths of all files in a folder to a txt file C# .NET
I'm trying to write the file paths of all files in a folder to a .txt file:
string logFilePfad = @"..\example\folder";    
string txtLogDatei = Path.Combine(logFilePfad, "LogFile.txt");
string[] files = Array.Empty<string>();     
 try
 {
     files = Directory.GetFiles(topicPfad);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 { 
     MessageBox.Show("Error when getting files/file names: " + ex.Message);
 }
 
 try
 {
     System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(txtLogDatei, files);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Error at WriteAllLines " + ex);
 }

Everything seems to work except WriteAllLines: I get a string array (string[] files) and it is not empty. When I iterate over the array (e.g. with MessageBox.Show), I can output all the file names from the folder, but nothing seems to happen when I use WriteAllLines. I don't get any exception either.
Is there something wrong with the string array "files"? When I manually create a list of string (e.g. string[] files = { "file1", "file2", "file3" };) it works.

Perhaps the log file is being created and written to somewhere other than where you expect... Try calling Path.GetFullPath(txtLogDatei) to see the actual resolved file path

Could you debug? What value do you see for txtLogDatei when you debug? I see undeclared variable: topicPfad

"When I manually create a list of string it works" - This implies to me a mistake or false assumption in debugging.  An array of strings is an array of strings in both cases.

I checked with Path.GetFullPath(txtLogDatei). the path is correct. When I delete it, it is created again where I expect it to be.

@mbur_1: just to clarify: you have used the debugger in the line System.IO.File.WriteAllLines and inspected the files variable and saw that it was not empty? The file LogFile.txt was also not opened in an editor while you were using WriteAllLines?

@Kangkan The variable topicPfad is declared in another spot. I have also checked it, it is correct. When I debug txtLogDatei I get the full correct path to the .txt file.

I ran this code with little change - replaced topicPfad with logFilePfad and  MessageBox.Show with 'Console.WriteLine'. And it is working nicely.

@TimSchmelter I've double checked this. I'm sure. I also inspected the files variable. Data type is correct and it is not empty. I can iterate over it and output every element from it.

Try following:
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(txtLogDatei, string.Join("\r\n", files));


Did you try that?  What happened when you did?
